# Qt MouseEvent Simulation on Desktop

Tags: windows, qt, mouseevent

I am getting `MouseEvent` Over the network and firing them through `postEvent` But not Working

```
QApplication::postEvent(DG::Util::_desktopWidget, ev);
```

DG::Util::_desktopWidget is being initialized in `_init`

```
QDesktopWidget* desktopWidget = new QDesktopWidget;//desktopWidget  is local
DG::Util::_desktopWidget = desktopWidget->screen(desktopWidget->primaryScreen());
```

Comment: I have not used QDesktopWidget and am unaware of whether or not it can be used in this manner. However, did you check if the QDesktopWidget ever gets the event? Did you check if the QDesktopWidget has any children?

Comment: `DG::Util::_desktopWidget` is of type `QWidget*` and how can I check Wheather it gets the mouseevent or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the event (`ev`) you are receiving from the network is valid?

Anyway, try using `QApplication::sendEvent` instead.